# The eigenvector of toeplitz matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, tridiagonal-matrices, toeplitz-matrices

The Toeplitz matrix is

\begin{align*}
T_r(a,b,c)=
 \begin{bmatrix}
    b & c  \\
    a & b & c\\
   &a&b&c\\
     &&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
     &&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
     &&&&\ddots&\ddots&\ddots\\
     &&&&&\ddots&\ddots&c\\
     0&&&&&&a&b
  \end{bmatrix}
\end{align*}

I found that the eigenvalue $\lambda_j$ of this matrix = $b+2c\sqrt{\frac{a}{c}}\cos(\frac{j\pi}{N+1}), \quad j=1,\dots,N$.

Thus, I'll only check that the eigenvectors $\vec{v_j}$ according to the eigenvalues $\lambda_j$ be $(v_1,v_2,\dots,v_N)^{T}$, where $v_k=2(\sqrt{\frac{a}{c}})^k\sin(\frac{kj\pi}{N+1}), \quad k=1,\dots,N$.

Since I knew the eigenvalue, I tried $T_r(a,b,c)\vec{v_j}=\lambda_j\vec{v_j}$. At first row, we could get 
\begin{align*}
bv_1+cv_2&=\lambda_jv_1\\
&=bv_1+2c\sqrt{\frac{a}{c}}\cos(\frac{j\pi}{N+1})v_1
\end{align*}
This implies that $v_2=2\sqrt{\frac{a}{c}}\cos(\frac{j\pi}{N+1})v_1$.
How to get explicit the eigenvector according to the eigenvalue although we don't know $v_1$??

Any help is appreciated...

Thank you!

Comment: seems (underlined) to understand that you " forgot" that the eigenvectors are defined unless for a multiplicative constant.

Comment: Umm... you mean that $v_1$ can be set $2\sqrt{\frac{a}{c}}\sin(\frac{j\pi}{N+1})$ since this is constant. Right?

Comment: yes, to express an eigenvector you have to normalize it somehow: or by fixing the modulus or by fixing one of the (non-null) components  to a non-null constant (thereafter, you  put a $c*$ in front of it )